# Access violation on send email with attachment

Tags: delphi, smtp, gmail, delphi-7, indy

```
var
  IdEnviar: TIdMessage;
```

---

If I send an email, it works fine

```
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Host :=  'smtp.gmail.com';
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Port := 587;
```

but if I try to add attachment adding this 3 lines:

```
IdEnviar.MessageParts.Clear;
IdAttachmentFile1.Create(IdEnviar.MessageParts, 'c:\file.png');
IdAttachmentFile1.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
```

I get an access violation error.

I'm using the last indy10 files

Comment: You know how to create an instance? `MyFoo := TFoo.Create;`

Comment: I think i had instances of all objects

  IdSMTP1:=TIdSmtp.Create(nil);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    IdEnviar:=TIdMessage.Create(nil);

the code compile right, and if  I don't use attachment, the email send fine, my issue is with attachment

Comment: And what about `IdAttachmentFile1.Create(IdEnviar.MessageParts, 'c:\file.png');`?

Comment: do you mean add it in var? I did it too
var
  IdAttachmentFile1:TIdAttachmentfile;

Comment: I mean you should create an instance with `TIdAttachmentFile.Create(...)` that is how you must create an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a serious error:

```
IdAttachmentFile1.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
```

You've failed to create the `TIdAttachmentFile` properly, so you're trying to set a property on an object that doesn't exist, and thus getting the AV.

The proper way to accomplish this is to assign the result of `TIdAttachmentFile.Create` to a variable, and then set that variable's `ContentType`:

```
var
  Attachment: TIdAttachmentFile;

Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdEnviar.MessageParts, 'c:\file.png');
Attachment.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
```